# Mapping PostgreSQL bit(n) in JPA (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, bitmap

I'm trying to map a postgres bit(n) or bit varying(n) column in JPA (with hibernate as the provider).

Is there an already established java type that will be automatically mapped (I've already tried `byte[]`)? If not then how can this be done?

Comment: Did you ever solve this Problem?

Comment: @JonasMichel I don't recall if I ever solved it in hibernate. I switched to JOOQ shortly after and became a much happier person.